# Who controls the Twitter account?

Tags: discussion, publicity

I follow the [MSE Twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/StackMath), and was wondering who decides which questions (main and/or meta) to "tweet". Is the selection automated, akin to the way "Community" operates?

Maybe this is common knowledge, but I couldn't find any info on meta...

Comment: [Minitrue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Truth).

Comment: TWIMC: one tweet every three hours is a bit much...

Answer (score 3):

Huh, I didn't know it existed until you asked. A bit of search digs up [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/) introducing the Twitter user. Jeff indicates [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101340/155238) that the tweets include Site Blogs, Moderator-initiated Chat Events, and "Interesting Questions" (though I am not sure how that is determined, but evidently it is automated).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll have to remember to check blog/meta.SO in the future!

Comment: I found out by seeing that there's a "tweeted" entry in the revision history of the tweeted questions, e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/36420/revisions).